# Transform a view to look like a curve in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I need help with this design. I just wanna know to transform a textview into a form. Im using react native expo cli for my application

I've tried using Transform ScaleX and ScaleY, but it changes the size of the text. I need alternate solution for this[image]

Comment: Do you mean TextInput or view of the text?

Comment: Did you try to work with Svg : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/svg/

Comment: @ShoebMirza TextInput!

Comment: @Oleg I've tried using svg but I get only circle shape. Im not able to place the text below the circle, its upside down.

Comment: No way, you can make background like in attached picture with input but not input itself